# How to stop a rails controller from executing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following piece of code

```
def show
    unless logged_in?
      login_required
      return
    end
    #some additional code
    #that should only execute
    #if user is logged in
end
```

This works perfectly.
Now I'd like to move the login check into a before filter.
The problem is, that when I return from a method outside of show, it doesn't stop the execution of show... how do i stop `show` from going through with the code from an external method (i.e. one that could be called from a before filter)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you return false from a before_filter, then execution of the request will immediately stop.

If you just make your login_required method return false (or redirect) if they aren't logged in, and make it return true if they are, then just `before_filter :login_required`, it should work perfectly.

Edit: As Lenry states below, this will not work in Rails 2.0.1+
      Instead, to stop the request use `head :ok` in your code

Comment: This is no longer valid. Check the answer from Lenny below.

Answer (score 22):

In rails versions 2.0.1 and above, you need to redirect or send a response to halt execution of the action.

From [Agile Web Development with Rails Errata](https://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/errata#erratum-row-45840):

> #45840: The following is incorrect:
>
> "If a before filter returns false, processing of the filter chain terminates, and the action is not run. A filter may also render output or redirect requests, in which case the original action never gets invoked."
>
> A before_filter does not stop processing the filter chain on on return false any longer.
>
> From release notes of Rails 2.0.1: 
>   * Changed before_filter halting to happen automatically on render or redirect but no longer on simply returning false [David Heinemeier Hansson]
>
> --Rob Christie

`redirect_to`, `render`, and `head` will all halt execution. For example, `head :ok` will respond to the request with only the OK HTTP response code, and the action will not execute.

Comment: Unless the `render` call is inside a filter chain, a call to `render` *won't* halt execution of the controller action. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors)

Comment: If render halts execution, why do you get a double render error if you render twice?

Comment: The important distinction here is those 3 methods must be called from the `before_filter` in order to halt execution.

Comment: if you want to use render and stop the action you need to write it like `render :failed and return` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors

Answer (score 0):

To halt callback chain in Rails 5 you can use

```
    throw :abort
```

Comment: I don't understand where the best place is, to `catch` this thrown symbol. If I want to introduce some logic common to all controllers, that prevents further processing, and I throw `:abort` in `ApplicationController`, where do I catch it?

Comment: thow :abort is only for model validations and not Controllers.

Comment: A followup to @sameers question: So what do we do now if we had pre-processing happening in controllers? Prior to Rails 5, I would perform a render in a `before_action` specifying the appropriate error message and status, and return `false`, which would halt the processing chain. How do I perform the same action as before, now that processing chains aren't halted by returning `false`?